# using sed to find and replace, not adding

Tags: sed

I have a simple text of URLs in stdout. Part of the URL looks as below.

```
https://somedomain./xx?t=s&u=random other text
```

I wish to change this using sed or something from the command line to read

```
https://somedomain./xx?t=l&u=random other text
```

I have used `sed -e 's/s&/l&/'`

Instead of replacing `s&` with `l&` I am getting `ls&` in the string. Is there something wrong with my command?

Answer (score 4):

You must escape the "&" character on the right-hand side of the `s` command by adding a "\" before it. Without it, "&" is special and is replaced by what is matched by the regular  expression. On the left hand side, "&" is not special and is guaranteed to be non-special. You don't want to escape it as while `&` would never be special, `\&` is not guaranteed to be and what it matches is unspecified.

So:

```
sed -i 's/s&/l\&/g' file.txt
```

Comment: not needed in the left hand side.

Comment: @don_crissti, not only it's not _needed_, but it's also better to avoid it as while `&` is _guaranteed_ to be non-special on the lhs, the behaviour for `\&` is unspecified, some implementations may treat it specially (if not now, maybe in a future version).